# Javascript - what files type choose to save pixels data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, save, size

How to save (with the lowest file size) pixels data in javascript?

For now I'm using JSON and it is looking like this:

```
 {"SIZE":[120,120],
  "FRAME":["SHINE",""],
  "LEDS":[
       {"X":0,"Y":0,"R":16,"G":30,"B":58},
       {"X":1,"Y":0,"R":13,"G":23,"B":43},
       {"X":2,"Y":0,"R":14,"G":26,"B":50},
  etc...
```

So for little pictures like 16x16, 90x32 the file size is ok but now I need do pictures 120x120 and file size is around 500kb. Is there any better solution for that?

Comment: Is your data create coherent space? Are you define all pixels (120x120)?

Comment: No. I define all pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options to send your pixels data in minimal size. The easiest way is to pack all this pixel information in one binary data.

1. MIME type

You can send image data with http request using i.e. `image/bmp` MIME type. You can view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data to check how to read that kind of data

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      // do something with each byte in the array
    }
  }
};

oReq.send(null);
```

2. Convert to binary and send it as BASE64

You can convert your pixels data to binary format (similar to pure BMP) and then use [BASE64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) algorithm to represent it with letters. Then you can send it with regular JSON

This is very good explanation about packing complex structures to binary: http://danthedev.com/2015/07/25/binary-in-javascript/

Comment: Yup i did, gonna check both. Thanks.